# Strange String.split("\n") behavior

Tags: java, split

I have a .txt text file, containing some lines..
I load the contain using the RequestBuilder object, and split the responseText with
words = String.split("\n"); but i wonder, why the result is contains the "\n" part..
For example, my text:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

the result is,

```
words[0] = "abc\n"
words[1] = "def\n"
words[2] = "ghi\n"
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your lines are terminated with `\n`? They might be terminated with `\r\n`, or something else even.

Comment: ohh it can be possible, can you tell me how can i check it ? so what's created when i press enter in my text editor ?

Comment: You can always .trim() the result and I think it'll remove whatever's there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows carriage returns (`"\r\n"`) shouldn't make a visible difference to your results, nor should you need to escape the regular expression you pass to `String.split()`.

Here's proof of both the above using `str.split("\n")`: http://ideone.com/4PnZi

If you *do* have Windows carriage returns though, you should (although strictly not necessary) use `str.split("\r\n")`: http://ideone.com/XcF3C

Comment: Great! your answer make everything clear, but in text editor, how can i made text that terminated with \n ? so \r\n is only in windows ?

Comment: @amateurs Many Windows applications will use `\r\n` to end a line, while Linux and other applications use `\n`. If you want to strip the carriage returns (`\r`) in Java, use `str.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n")`. Finding a Windows application that doesn't use carriage returns in the first place, that you'll have to ask someone else.

Comment: this split expression did not work to split multi line input in a chrome browser.

Answer (score 22):

Try using `string.split("\\n+")`. Or even better - `split("[\\r\\n]+")`

Comment: but would that not also skip empty lines? (maybe wished)

Comment: This isn't necessary, see my answer.

Comment: the double backslash is unnecessary. Regex already designates backslash for escaped constructs like "\n". See "Backslashes, escapes and quotiong", http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 13):

You may also want to consider `String[] lines = text.split("\\\\n");`

Comment: Because Java needs regex to be a String literal. You have your \n but \ is also special in regex. To complicate things, the way you escape in regex is also with \. So you need to escape it again to make \\n which seems like it should be enough.. for regex.. but Java takes regex patterns as Strings.  It sees you as escaping the \\n to make just n.  With \\\n Java sees a \\n and regex thinks you mean \n, but \ is still seen as a special character in regex.  So regex \\ = \  and Java \\ = \  which leaves you with the \\n that java finally sees as \n.  Ended up escaping stuff just now, heh.

Answer (score 3):

If split uses regex you should use "\\n" instead of "\n"

Comment: cool. Thanks. I didn't want to rely on memory without double checking from the doc. So, left this to OP to look to. :)

Comment: Although `String.split()` does take a regex, this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try using  `string.split("\\\\n")` . It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's trivial, but the .split method is sensitive to spaces and text breaks. If we don't know how the original text is written, we have to consider that this could make some differences (single line, breaks, multilines, etc).

Single line text:

```
const inlineText = "Hello world!";
console.log(inlineText.split(' ')) //['Hello', 'world!']
```

Multi lines text:

```
const multilinesText = `
Hello world!
`
console.log(multilinesText.split(' ')) // ['\nHello', 'world!', '\n']
```