# Java StringTokenizer how to find the end of the paragraph?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am study Java String Tokenizer. I am looking for the way to find end of the paragraph.

For example, I have one text file..

```
HI
I am bob the the bob

And I am am  bob bob bob lu the the 

hello
```

I am reading  txt file and I am using the String Tokenizer to put each word to hashtable

However, I would like to stop when paragraph is end.
for example,

First, I want to store

```
"HI
I am bob the the bob"
```

Second, when we see double newlines, we stop. and insert "1" in the hashtable.
then i would like to insert

```
"And I am am  bob bob bob lu the the "
```

Third, when we see the double newline again , then we stop again.
And we insert "2" in the hashtable

then

we insert "hello" into the hashtable.

However, I am not really sure the way to stop at the end of each paragraph ?

does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: It appears you have the answer, stop when you have a blank line.

Comment: This might prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539878/strange-string-split-n-behavior

Comment: how to we know when it is stop ? do we have to use ascii code to check the black line ?

Comment: I think BufferedReader will be helpful here to check each line from readLine() method whether it is an empty line or not

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using empty space(" ") as delimiter. I would try to use second Tokenizer with "\n" as delimiter, parse the file with it, and then use your delimiter for every token.

As the matter of fact, every empty line among tokens after using first tokenizer is an end of paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Detecting double new line is not the sring tokenizer responsibility. You are using tokenizer to split one line to separate words. But I guess you have an outer loop that reads lines. When you detect empty line the paragraph ends.

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   if ("".equals(line.trim())) {
      // empty line  - new paragraph. 
   }
}
```