# need to retrieve data from the database

Tags: android, database, swipeview

I have a very long string in the database that needs to be retrieved into a swipe view.

But,the problem is that the string comprises of set of "**\n\n**"

Whenever it is separated with this expression i need to put it in another slide,i mean i am using SWIPE view here..

```
if(tablecolumn==\\n\\n)
    {
         code to break it to parts   
    }
```

Is this how i should be doing it?

If i am wrong,how to break this string to different parts and enable it into **SWIPE VIEW** in to different swipe view?

Comment: try to use String.split("\n\n") check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539878/strange-string-split-n-behavior?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Amitabh Sarkar,i will try and let you know the result.

Comment: Amitabh Sarkar,NO its not working for ANDROID.it is asking for adding cast to the textview.
But,i hav aldready added a cast to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply break your string comprising of a special character like this :-

```
    String str ="mynameisjhon.yournameisdash.bla";
```

, here you have a string concatenated with " . " (period character)

to break this string do this :-

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "."); //break the string whenever "." occurs
    String temp =st.nextToken(); // it will have "my name is jhon" break
    String temp2 = st.nextToken();// it will have "your name is dash"
    String temp3 = st.nextToken();//it will have "bla"
```

now your string is breaked into parts!
 Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Load the whole string into your ViewAdapter and seperate it via substring 
or load the string in your Activity/Fragment seperate it via substring, put the strings in an ArrayList, an initiate your ViewAdapter with the ArrayList as data source

either way use substring

Comment: Nickolaus,i did not get you

Comment: I suppose you have a long string in your database field, load it via a cursor then get the parts of the string, via substring, then you have each string and can put it into your view(s)