# Break up the text on the page

Tags: java, android

I have a string

```
String str = "line1"+"\n" +
               "line2"+"\n" +
               "line3"+"\n" +
               "line4"+"\n" +
               "line5"+"\n" +
               "line6"+"\n" +
               "line7"+"\n" +
               "line8"+"\n" +
               "line9"+"\n" +
               "line10"+"\n" +
               "line11"+"\n" +
               "line12"+"\n" +
               "line13"+"\n" +
               "line14"+"\n" +
               "line15"+"\n" +
               "line16"+"\n" +
               "line17"+"\n";
```

I want to get out of it an array of strings

```
String str1 =      "line1"+"\n" +
                   "line2"+"\n" +
                   "line3"+"\n" +
                   "line4"+"\n";

String str2 =      "line5"+"\n" +
                   "line6"+"\n" +
                   "line7"+"\n" +
                   "line8"+"\n";

String str3 =      "line9"+"\n" +
                   "line10"+"\n" +
                   "line11"+"\n" +
                   "line12"+"\n";

String str4 =      "line13"+"\n" +
                   "line14"+"\n" +
                   "line15"+"\n" +
                   "line16"+"\n";

String str5 =       "line17"+"\n";
```

if I do so

```
 String[] str1 = str.split("\n");
```

I get an array of strings, in which only one line, and I need it for a few
instead of the string I will have the file from which I plan to read the text in a row

Comment: the answer is given please have a look and try with that

Answer (score 0):

for splitting string with particular format you need to specify regular expression 
so in your case regular expression will be ("\r\n")

[Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539878/strange-string-split-n-behavior)

Comment: almost) I want a function that will be out of my line to do an array of strings. And in each row of the array should get 4 or 6 or N lines from the original string